# IAP Invalid product ids while App Store reviews, but it's ok in sandbox and testflight

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to integrate In-App-Purchases in my app. I have used a thrd party library, **SwiftyStoreKit**, as IAP helper.
It works fine when I use my device to test in-app purchases **in sandbox**, Whether run from **xcode** or **testflight**. 
But it shows **'SKError.paymentInvalid'** while **App Store** reviews it. It's really frustrating, I don't know how to fix it. I've tried reaching out to the review team but they only linked me with articles on IAP and testing my app. 
The code for the user to click to purchase is below. When the App tore is reviewing the purchase, a **.paymentInvalid** error will be thrown, Any ideas appreciated...

```
func purchaseProduct(item: RCCoinItem) -> Promise<RCInAppPurSucceed> {
    return Promise { (seal) in
        SVHud.show(status: "Purchasing...", maskType: .clear)
        RCDataAnalysis.track(eventName: "ClickBuyCoin", params: ["p_id" : item.type, "dollar" : "\(item.cost)"])
        SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(item.type, quantity: 1, atomically: false) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let product):
                // fetch content from your server, then:
                if let receiptData = SwiftyStoreKit.localReceiptData {
                    let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                    NW.request(path: APPLE_SUB, method: .post, params: ["receipt-data" : receiptString, "product_id" : item.type]).done { (response) in
                            SVHud.dismiss()
                            if let dict = response as? [String : Any] {
                                print("purchse == \(dict)")
                                if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                                    SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
                                }
                                
                                if let inapp = RCInAppPurSucceed.deserialize(from: dict) {
                                    let realm = try! Realm()
                                    try! realm.write {
                                        Login.shared.user.coins = inapp.coins
                                        Login.shared.user.firstRecharged = true
                                    }
                                    inapp.coins = item.coins
                                    seal.fulfill(inapp)
                                }
                                
                                RCDataAnalysis.track(eventName: "BuyCoinSuccess", params: ["p_id" : item.type, "dollar" : "\(item.cost)"])
                                
                                print("Purchase Succeed: \(product.productId)")
                            } else {
                                RCDataAnalysis.track(eventName: "BuyCoinFail", params: ["p_id" : item.type, "reason" : "api wrong"])
                                seal.reject(NWError(msg: "Something is wrong with Apple_Sub Api.", code: 201))
                                SVHud.showError(status: "Api succeed, but something wrong happened, please try agin.")
                            }
                        }.catch{ (error) in
                            seal.reject(NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Something is wrong with Apple_Sub Api."]))
                            SVHud.showError(status: "Something is wrong with Apple_Sub Api, Please try agin.")
                            RCDataAnalysis.track(eventName: "BuyCoinFail", params: ["p_id" : item.type, "reason" : "api wrong response"])
                        }
                }
            case .error(let error):
                if !self.retrieved {
                    self.retrieveProductInfo()
                }
                
                switch error.code {
                case .unknown:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "Unknown error. Please try again")
                case .clientInvalid:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "Not allowed to make the payment")
                case .paymentCancelled:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "The payment is canceled.")
                case .paymentInvalid:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "The purchase identifier was invalid.")
                case .paymentNotAllowed:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "The device is not allowed to make the payment")
                case .storeProductNotAvailable:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "The product is not available in the current storefront")
                case .cloudServicePermissionDenied:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
                case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "Could not connect to the network")
                case .cloudServiceRevoked:
                    SVHud.showInfo(status: "User has revoked permission to use this cloud service")
                default:
                    SVHud.showError(status: (error as NSError).localizedDescription)
                    print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
                }
                
                RCDataAnalysis.track(eventName: "BuyCoinFail", params: ["p_id" : item.type, "reason" : "apple \(error.code.rawValue)"])
                seal.reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "But it shows 'invalid product id' while App Store reviews it"  What is your question?  If you are asking "What am I doing wrong," we don't even know where you see 'invalid product id.'  Not everybody uses SwiftyStoreKit.

Comment: Hi，I edit my question, please review it, thanks!

Comment: Go to SwiftyStoreKit's site, click on Issues.  Then search for 'paymentInvalid.'

Comment: It's no offense to the guy who has developed it, but I never use somebody else's CocoaPods.  I would rather develop everything for myself so that I can fix bugs myself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a code problem. I also use SKProductRequest to request the product list of the last reviewed version, but it can't get too.

Comment: Looking at the source code, `paymentInvalid` is returned if the requested product identifier is in the "invalid product identifiers" returned when fetching products.  Does your app retrieve the available products before making the purchase interface available?.  I would also agree with El Tomato.  SwiftyStoreKit is complex code on top of an already tricky API.  Converting it from delegate-based to closure based might make it more "swifty" but it also makes it much more complicated.  I always build my own purchasing code.

Comment: Using StoreKit isn't very difficult.  You are better-off doing it on your own.

Comment: @Paulw11 indeed, my app retrieves products many times but always get a empty array of products during App Store review, even use SKProductRequest through my own code, it's weird and confused me. So I can't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you, I will try with my own code. Hope it will succeed. it really draws me mad.